# Using cor.test() on columns with na's

Tags: r, statistics, data-analysis

When I'm trying to calculate the spearman correlations of one column on another dataframe, everytime I use `cor.test(dfx, dfy, method = c("spearman"), na.action = "na.exclude")` it throws an error saying that x and y must have the same length. I have used `cor()` to do the same thing while specifying "complete.obs" which worked perfectly fine but I need to have the P values for each obs as well.

```
Age Male (1,0) Female (1,0) Other (race) Caucasian (1,0)
1  83          1            0            0               1
2  91          1            0            0               1
3  87          1            0            0               1
4  89          0            1            0               1
5  78          1            0            0               1
6  84          0            1            0               1
```

here's a sample of the 352x52 table. I'm comparing it to a column of 352x1 and there are a few NA's throughout, so I'm trying to figure out how to handle this and get the P value's reported.

Comment: Assume `dfx` is table's 1st column and `dfy` is 2nd column. if `dfx` has `NA` with 5 and `dfy` has `NA` with 0. Their length will be different, and causes error. so You should consider for if some index of `dfx` has `NA`, than discard same index for `dfy` also. Try this first and let me know result.

Comment: right...I'm asking how to specify to ignore these NA's, as the cor() function has an argument to ignore the NA's between each, but it does not calculate the p values which i need

Comment: select `NA` value with `which(is.na())` and remove that index also.

Comment: could you provide an example for applying the which(is.na()) function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this, first I make an example dfx and dfy with some missing values:

```
set.seed(100)
M = matrix(rnorm(352*53),ncol=53)
#make some NAs
M[sample(length(M),500)] = NA
dfy = M[,1]
dfx = M[,-1]
```

You use apply to iterate through the columns, and you take only those that are not NAs in that column and y:

```
res = apply(dfx,2,function(i){
   compl = !is.na(i) & !is.na(dfy)
   unlist(cor.test(i[compl],dfy[compl],method="spearman")[c("estimate","p.value")])
})

res = t(res)

head(res)
     estimate.rho   p.value
[1,]  -0.03147103 0.5675366
[2,]  -0.06137428 0.2596360
[3,]  -0.06224493 0.2536336
[4,]  -0.02586685 0.6354243
[5,]   0.06105610 0.2642532
```

Comment: Error in cor.test.default(i[compl], df1[compl], method = "spearman") : 
 I tried it with a newer cleaned up df, and got the error " not enough finite observations
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

Comment: in the data explorer, i dont see any that are all NA's

Comment: and did you do table(colSums(!is.na(dfx))==0)  and double check that there are no NAs, i have no clue what is a data explorer

Comment: I think i found the source of many errors in those NA columns....thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Thats great :) glad you figured it out

Comment: if you have the time, would you mind explaining what you did with the apply function? step by step? that would be amazing just so i can use it in other scenarios if necessary

Comment: ok we can start with the code the apply.. what you need is a function, that can take in 2 vectors, subset the common non-NA values, and calculate correlation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212562/discussion-between-stupidwolf-and-medlearning).